# How can I log all output from a docker container to process 1, in order to see them in docker logs?

Tags: docker, logging, process, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that defines over a dozen services to be run. I have a CLI that can start or stop the services, etc... Now, I can run `docker-compose logs -f` in the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file to view what I believe is the stdout and stderr from each of the containers process running on `PID 1`.

So now, for example, some of my services contain a python-Django app, and the `command` defined on the service (in the compose file) runs the server and then `tail -f <some_log_file>`. So I see that as the command on `PID 1`, with the server running on a new PID eg 7, and the tail -f command on PID eg 8. Now, I know I can't kill any of these PID's as that will issue an `exit with code 137` command to the container. The server has also started $n$ extra processes, which are gunicorn workers.

Up until now, in development, if I want to check out new code and debug, I would `docker exec` into the container, kill the worker processes, and then issue another run server command, starting up new workers, showing me all output, not just what I have set up my logger to print out. This is because once I do this, the output from `docker-compose logs`, no longer outputs what is being output in the container, this is because of what I believe docker only logs what is output on PID 1, or processes directly spawned from it. (I would also like to know exactly how it is doing this.)

Now, poking around how to do this, I saw that the [official Dockerfile for nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L21-L23) contains:

```
# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Which I beleive should allow nginx to write to these `.log` locations, while also having the output piped to stdout and stderr, but then realizing that `docker logs` does not read directly from stdout or stderr

And then with [this link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19616#issuecomment-174355979),

```sh
ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/test.log
```

Should be able to write to a `.log` file, with the output also directed to whatever docker needs to be able to output to `docker-compose logs`, but this doesn't work either.

So, how can I successfully start another process in a container, with **ALL** output piped into the output of `PID 1`?

Comment: you need to redirct all the logs to stdout

Comment: But I don't just want the logs, I want the entire output that would be output by the terminal, not just the logs. With python you can write to stdout with `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`, and also writing to a file with `logging.FileHandler(dev_stdout_file)`, but as I said, it is just the logs.

Comment: do mean printing in python? print("test", flush=True) will print also to docker output. or better using `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: I am confused by that statement, running a container, and then exec into it, and then starting a python console/script with the commands you just suggested will not be visable in docker logs